# What does the dash mean in windows command line syntax?

Tags: c++, windows, command-line, command-line-arguments

I know basic c++ coding and command line syntax. Often, the main() function looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argc[])
```

When I execute my program via command line, I just do this:

```
cd c:\path\to\foo 1
```

Where 1 is the argument. And of course, arc would be equal to '2' and the '1' would be at element '1' of the array argc (as opposed to 0).

I've seen the dash used in a lot of places. Specifically:

```
gcc -v
```

And if I type just 'gcc', it says there are no arguments. And if I type 'gcc v' I get "error: no such file or directory". But when I take a look at the minGW bin folder where gcc is, there is no folder 'v'.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command-line_option

Comment: Okay. So they specify options. I'd really appreciate an example C++ code that must be started with foo -v as opposed to foo v.

Comment: I know there's Boost's Program Options library. Other than that, and the getopt library mentioned in an answer, I don't know of any. It boils down to taking your arguments and parsing them.

Comment: Oh! I understand what paddy meant then. So the whole argument is -v and the program simply looks for the '-v' which indicates the next element in the array is the argument it was looking for. It is simply string analysis. Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a style of setting options in programs.  It comes from the `getopt` library provided in Unix/Linux etc.  The `--` form that kc7zax mentions in their answer is the long-form of these options (allowing a long identifier instead of a single character).

There's nothing magic about these.  They are simply parsed out of the `argv` array.  You can implement similar or identical functionality yourself if you want.  But it's a pain.  That's why libraries exist.

Answer (score 4):

It is simply a standard for identifying the name of a command line parameter from the parameter value that may exist.  e.g. gcc -o myfile.o

The windows world usually sees a - or a / as the marker.  I've often encountered a -- in the unix/bsd world as well.

Comment: How would this be implemented in the main method of a c++ code? What I understood is we are giving a name to a parameter value. But are these values mapped or something according to the marker?

Comment: Yes, this is done from the main method.  The parameters passed to main will contain what the user typed.  The program then analyzes the input and decides if it knows what to do with the parameters.  As mentioned by @paddy there are a number of libraries that will do this for you.